# How to prevent automatic displaying explorer when we connect to share folder

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

When I connect to a shared folder on another computer, Windows automatically displays Windows Explorer in this shared folder.

How can I connect to the shared folder without automatically displaying Windows Explorer?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the command line and mapping it to a drive:

```
net use * \\server\folder * /USER:Username
```